# apache mod_rewrite user URLs to index.php

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've always had a fairly standard apache configuration. Right now we're introducing a new concept, user session specific URLs that's going to change things. Basically we have a DocumentRoot and anything such as:

`http://example.com/` would hit index.html in the `DocumentRoot` directive.

But now I'd like to be able to do something like

`http://example.com/uid/5/` 
`http://example.com/uid/2`

Those should still hit index.html in the DocumentRoot that has been set. The URL is mostly for server-side and client-side scripts to be able to carry out their own tasks.

What's the best way to handle this in Apache? Is mod_rewrite even necessary here?

I also need to be able to support existing paths such as say the following:

`http://example.com/foo/bar/something.php` will be rewritten to `http://example.com/uid/3/foo/bar/something.php` but will still hit the same place on the filesystem as before.

Comment: You probably do need mod_rewrite. Does `/uid/3/foo/bar/something.php` actually exist as a full path with all real directories?

Comment: `foo/bar/something.php` exists on the filesystem underneath DocumentRoot. `/uid/3` is a 'virtual path` I'm adding across the board. note: `foo/bar/something.php` already works by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `mod_rewrite` by putting this code in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uid/([1-9][0-9]*)/(.+)$ /$2?uid=$1 [L]
```

Example:
http://example.com/foo/bar/something.php -> unchanged
http://example.com/uid/3/foo/bar/something.php -> rewritten to `/foo/bar/something.php?uid=3`

---

EDIT: without uid appended

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uid/[1-9][0-9]*/(.+)$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: what if I do not wish to append `uid=3` as a query string? I'd like to leave the URL as is, but make sure it hits the right path on the filesystem.

Comment: I made it as an example, if you don't want it you can get rid of it (see my edited answer)